# SwiftUI contextMenu showing only children contextMenu and not parent

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a macOS app in SwiftUI, and I have 2 `.contextMenu` in both the parent text and the list of children objects.

It is only showing the `contextMenu` of the **children** objects even when I right click the parent label.

What am I doing wrong?

```
           List {
                VStack {
                    Text("Parent")
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button("Parent Action") {                                    
                            }
                        }
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("Child")
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button("Child Action") {
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
```

...

If I change the parent from List to ScrollView, it works but I do not want to waste all of the memory rendering each item upfront.

Comment: These two `Text`s are in the same list row. Is this intentional? Do you mind putting them in two different list rows instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above will combine the contents of `List` into a single item. So, when  `contextMenu` shows up, it's just recognizing the `Parent`. I believe the better approach is to separate `Parent` and `Child` into distinct `ForEach` to determine individual parent and child.

```swift
struct Child: Hashable {
    var name: String = ""

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Parent: Hashable {
    var childs: [Child] = []
    var name: String = ""
}

...
var list: [Parent] = [
    .init(childs: [.init("Child 1"), .init("Child 2")], name: "Parent")
]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(list, id: \.self) { p in
            HStack {
                Text(p.name)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button("Parent Action") {
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            ForEach(p.childs, id: \.self) { c in
                HStack {
                    Text(c.name)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button(c.name) {
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.leading)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```